# IronPython: instancemethod objects inherit operator overloads of the owning class

Tags: methods, operator-overloading, ironpython

I ran across a strange phenonemon with IronPython (2.7.5). Please take a look at the following example code:

```
class X(object):        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print "__eq__"
        return False

    def foo(self):
        return 1

a = X()

print a.foo == a.foo
```

When run with IronPython the output is:

```
__eq__
False
```

I don't understand why the equality operator overload of class X is used (a.foo has type instancemethod, not X).

When using CPython the output is

```
True
```

I guess this is a bug in IronPython. Does anyone agree?

Comment: For me it looks like a bug, `IronPython` should behave like `CPython`. Would you like to open an issue on `GitHub`? If you don't have any account, i would do this for you. Please let me know.

Comment: I don't have a GitHub account, sorry. I would appreciate if you could report this issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: ok, i reported the bug for you: https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/issues/1268